# Create a method which returns the class that i want to generate in Codemodel

Tags: sun-codemodel, jcodemodel

I need to generate a class which must have  a method that returns an object of the same class.

I want to generate something like this

```
public class A{
   public A method1(){
       ...
   }
 }
```

The problem is that I have to pass the Class object of the class  being returned by the method. If i do that, because my class is not built yet I will get a ClassNotFoundException. Is there a way of achieving this?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking to return `this` or a `new A()`?

Comment: It didn't matter because the problem was that i didn't know how to obtain a JClass reference for class A, since I thought you must provide the Class object representing your class in order to build its corresponding JClass object. Luckily, I managed to find the solution. Thanks for trying to help though !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a little digging I managed to find the solution. If you do not have access to a class and thus  you cannot provide its corresponding Class object, use the method directClass(String className) from Codemodel object  which takes as input a String representing the class name and returns the corresponding JClass object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CodeModel `JDefinedClass` to reference the containing class during class generation:

```
    JDefinedClass aClass = codeModel._class(JMod.PUBLIC, "A", ClassType.CLASS);
    JMethod method= aClass.method(JMod.PUBLIC, aClass, "method1");
    method.body()._return(JExpr._new(aClass));
```

Outputs:

```
public class A {
    public A method1() {
        return new A();
    }
}
```